# Executing emacs shortcuts when keyboard is set to Greek

Tags: key-bindings, evil, text-editing

Writing Greek in emacs is proving to be quite inconvenient. If my keyboard is set to Greek, normal shortcuts do not work and I have to switch to latin just to navigate around the buffer.

As an example, let's say I'm writing a Greek sentence and I want to go back a character to fix a mistake. The usual way is to press C-b, but because my keyboard is set to Greek, emacs actually receives C-β and gives me an error: "C-β is undefined". What I have to do next is press alt-shift to switch to latin, enter C-b again, and switch to Greek once again with alt-shift. Quite a hassle.

Is there a way around this? I could, of course, map C-β to do what C-b does, but I'd have to do that for hundreds of shortcuts.

It'd be nice if the solution worked for evil-mode, too.

Comment: The exact same thing happens to vim users as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776728/using-vim-with-the-greek-language

Comment: Have a look at [selecting the input method](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html).

Comment: Can you write up an answer explaining how you solved the problem and then accept it so that we can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the [input method](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html) of emacs.

The OS keyboard will remain set to English, but the latin keystrokes received by emacs will be re-interpreted to Greek ones. This will only happen when inserting text. Therefore, both emacs and evil-mode shortcuts will work properly even when the input method is set to Greek.

Adding the following to `.emacs` enables us to use `C-\` to toggle entering text in Greek.

```
(set-input-method "greek")
```

If `C-\` is inconvenient to type, it can be changed using `global-set-key`, ie

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-o") 'toggle-input-method)
```