# Using Emacs with Greek keyboard

Tags: key-bindings

I know I can use a Greek input method, but what I want is quite different: how to use Emacs in an OS configured for Greek, without having to set the keyboard to English (or any other Latin alphabet language) when wanting to use Emacs.

I know I can set my own keybindings, but it is not practical.  Should I just do so and create an ELPA package for Greek keybindings?

Comment: I haven't tried this package: https://github.com/a13/reverse-im.el but it sounds like it does what you want. In the example, change `russian-computer` to `greek`.

Comment: Interesting question! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639429/emacs-linux-and-international-keyboard-layouts) is a similar question with Russian, rather than Greek. Ignore the accepted answer as it suggests using input methods, which isn't what you want. Some of the others might perhaps be helpful. `reverse-im` suggested above, might be a better solution, though, as the package is newer than any of the answers. (Haven't tried any of the solutions.)

Comment: Thanks @legoscia for suggesting the answer, and aplaice for confirming it.  Am happy already.  I wrote an answer below, but as I cannot yet accept it, please feel free to write the answer and I will accept yours.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [Executing emacs shortcuts when keyboard is set to Greek](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12658/executing-emacs-shortcuts-when-keyboard-is-set-to-greek). *I would submit this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @legoscia for suggesting the answer, and @aplaice for confirming it: http://github.com/a13/reverse-im.el, available from ELPA, does what I needed.  Just changed `russian-computer` to `greek` in the sample initialisation code, and am happy.